# How can I edit the UI part of my Shiny app to change the colours of the slider text?

Tags: css, r, shiny

Specifically, I want the years below (i.e. 2015 and 2023) to be in black text instead of white.

The relevant part of the code to format the rest of the slider is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

 tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      /* Custom styles */
      .js-irs-0 .irs-bar, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, .js-irs-0 .irs-slider, .js-irs-0 .irs-min, .js-irs-0 .irs-max {
          background: #808080; /* Grey color for slider elements */
          border-color: #808080; /* Grey color for slider border */
  }
  
  .js-irs-0 .irs-line, .js-irs-0 .irs-from, .js-irs-0 .irs-to, .js-irs-0 .irs-single {
      background: #D3D3D3; /* Lighter grey color for the line */
  }
  
  .js-irs-0 .irs-grid-text {
      color: #000; /* Black color for the grid text (years) */
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a full reproducible example? When I use your CSS with a standard `sliderInput` those numbers are already grey, not white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify the `color` attribute. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-from, .irs-to {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: #808080 !important;
  }")),
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "myslider",
    label = "myslider",
    min = as.Date("2015-01-01"),
    max = as.Date("2023-12-31"),
    value = c(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31")),
    timeFormat = "%Y"
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]